# Git - update current branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have two branches, derived from master branch. In both branches are some different changes. How can I update changes in the branch 1. from the branch 2.? I dont want to merge them into one branch, only update. Something like this:

```
1.2.Master
| | |
|\| | //update
| | |
| | |
 \| |
   \|
    |
```

Comment: Merging branch 2 into branch 1 doesn't remove or change branch 2 in any way. Can you define what you mean by "update"?

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
git diff 2..1|patch
```

But using merge would be the way git prefers...

Like this:

```
git checkout 1
git merge 2
```